# Meteor add class to accounts-ui button

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I wan't to remove the dropdown and customize styling in accounts-ui. After some reading I have done this

```
#loginModal * {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

a#login-sign-in-link {
    display: none;
}

.login-close-text{
    display: none !important;
}

#loginModal{
    width: 100%;
}

.black{
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Now I open the dropdown and do some styling

```
Template.loginButtons.rendered = function()
{
    if (!this.rendered){
        Accounts._loginButtonsSession.set('dropdownVisible', true);
        $('.login-button').addClass('black');
        this.rendered = true;
    }
};
```

Opening of the dropdown works, but I can't add the black class to the buttons. I like the ui, I want to use most of the styling, just customize it a little bit. I might also want to use `$('.login-button').text('Login here!');` to change the text. The template is here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.html What should I do? Pasting the jquery command in the console changes the styling.

Comment: Have you tried the unstyled version of the package? https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-ui-unstyled

Comment: Yes, I want the default styling, I just want to add a class to the button

Comment: Why are you trying to do this when rendered is false? It could be that the elem doesn't exist yet. Maybe try taking the jquery out of the conditional block? Or remove the conditional block entirely? You could also try to run the jquery code in the rendered callback of another template that renders later, so you're sure the elem exists.